# Prove that the following program terminates

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms

I have tried searching for the following proof but couldn't find any result.

The question is to prove that the following program **will** terminate when its input x is a **positive integer**.

```
while x != 1 do
    if even(x)
        x = x / 2
    else
        x = 3*x+1
```

If there is any answer available, just provide the link.

The question is from the book **Programming Pearls** by **Jon Bentley** Second Edition (page 41)

Comment: See [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Comment: On the bright side, whoever answers this question as requested gets $500 from Erdős.

Comment: This problem has been open for a long time, as the Wikipedia article linked above by dtldarek explains.  The best results are [some heuristic arguments](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lagarias/paper/html/node3.html) that it terminates for almost all inputs (Lagarias, 1985).

Answer (score 0):

In 1972, J. H. Conway proved that a natural generalization of the Collatz problem is algorithmically undecidable

Specifically, he considered functions of the form

$$g(n) = a_i n + b_i,  {n\equiv i \pmod P}$$
where $$a_0,b_0,\dots,a_{P-1},b_{P-1}$$ are rational numbers which are so chosen that g(n) is always integral.

The standard Collatz function is given by $$P=2, a_0 = 1/2, b_0 = 0, a_1 = 3, b_1 = 1.$$ Conway proved that the problem:
Given g and n, does the sequence of iterates $$g^k(n)$$ reach 1?
is undecidable, by representing the halting problem in this way. Closer to the Collatz problem is the following universally quantified problem:

Given g does the sequence of iterates $$g^k(n)$$ reach 1, for all n>0?
Modifying the condition in this way can make a problem either harder or easier to solve (intuitively, it is harder to justify a positive answer but might be easier to justify a negative one). Kurtz and Simon proved that the above problem is, in fact, undecidable and even higher in the Arithmetical hierarchy, specifically $$\Pi^0_2-complete$$. This hardness result holds even if one restricts the class of functions g by fixing the modulus P to 6480 .

SOURCE:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)